# How to Count the object instace using Static property in C#.(Not using Costrutor0)

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio

I want to count the number of instance and I want to call The set accessor or Modifiers of property in c3 at the time of object creation can I?

call set at object

[image: call set at object]

```
class a {
 private static int x;
 public static int X {
  get {
   return x;
  }
  set { //Call This area while oblect Creation }
  }
 }
 class Program {
  static void Main(string[] args) {
   a o = new a();
   a ob = new a();
   Console.WriteLine("Count is: " + a.X);
  }
 }
```

Comment: Why can't you increment the static field in the constructor?

Comment: What issue do you face in using constructor?

Comment: No issue using constructor. But I m a student. In my college this challenge is given to me.

Comment: In that case I would make the constructor private so no instances can be made directly. On the class you can then add a static factory method, which does the increment and the instantiation (returning a new instance). Your client code would then look like a o = a.CreateInstance();

Comment: To me, the hint " //Call This area while oblect Creation" screams "in the constructor". Note that a simple increment here is not thread-safe could lead to under-counting if you have concurrent access

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you don't want to use a constructor to increment your `x` variable you can call a static method which increments the value of `x` and creates a new instance of your `a` class:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    a o = a.incrementX();
    a ob = a.incrementX();
    Console.WriteLine("Count is: " + a.X);
}
```

The static method `incrementX` is defined in your class:

```
class a
{
    private static int x;
    public static int X
    {
        get { return x; }
        set { x = value;}
    }
    public static a incrementX()
    {
        X++;
        return new a();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

To my mind, the only reasonably approach here is:

```
class a {
    private static int x;
    public static int X { get { return x; } }
    public a()
    {
        Interlocked.Increment(ref x);
    }
    ...
}
```

Now yes, the question title says "not using constructor", but: if you want to count how many instances of a type have been created - the appropriate place to put that code is *in the constructor*.

The `Interlocked.Increment(ref x);` could be replaced with `x++;` if you don't care about the answer being right when using multiple threads.

You could also satisfy the "not using constructor" by using a factory method:

```
private a() {}
public static a Create()
{
    Interlocked.Increment(ref x);
    return new a();
}
```

but if you do that, the `new a()` in the `Main()` method no longer works, and needs to be changed to `a.Create()`.

Answer (score 0):

use this:

```
class a
{
    private static int x;
    public static int X
    {
        get { return x; }
        set { //Call This area while oblect Creation }
     }
}
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        a o = new a();
        a.X += 1;
        Console.WriteLine("Count is: " + a.X);
    }
}
```

You access static field without initializing the object and so you set it's value.

Comment: Note: this isn't thread-safe, and could lead to under-call ring

Comment: He is not looking for a thread safe, he is looking for something that will work, for now. Dealing with thread safe will only confuse the op.

Comment: I realise that, but I try to consider not just the OP but also the next person who might find this via google search etc and doesn't have quite the same context. Making the gaps explicit is worthwhile, IMO